# New process after CoCreateInstance?

Tags: winapi, com

I'm fairly new to COM programming so please excuse if this is a stupid question.

After (successfully) creating a COM object using CoCreateInstance or CoCreateInstanceEx with class context CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER is there any way to tell if this call caused a new process to be spawned?

Comment: Not easily; not by any means built into COM. You could employ heuristics, e.g. run `EnumProcesses` before and after. As with any heuristic, this is not going to be 100% reliable (e.g. the user could happen to run the same executable manually at that exact time). Now, why do you care, if you don't mind me asking? What problem are you trying to solve, for which you expect this information to be helpful?

Comment: The reason I need this is I use api hooking to monitor behaviour of a process and I want to also monitor all processes spawned from it. (This is not malware, the user knows this is happening). I can easily hook into processes created through CreateProcess but I'm particularly interested in monitoring a (separate) explorer.exe instance and when you start "explorer.exe /separate" what happens is that the created process calls CoCreateInstance to create a new explorer process and then the original process exits.

Comment: What I'm currently doing is: After CoCreateInstance was invoked I find out the pid of the process (which is complicated enough) but that process might have been running already. I then use GetProcessTimes to find out if the process was started after my call to CoCreateInstance.
This is similar to the EnumProcesses approach but I was hoping for something 100% reliable. I don't want my hooking lib to "infect" processes the user didn't intend to monitor.

Comment: When you ask for an out-of-process server and CoCreateInstance() did not fail then you have a 100% guarantee that, yes, a process got started.  You just have no idea *where* it is running.  Or what its name might be.  It could well be one that runs on a machine thousands of miles removed from yours.  Never ever make the mistake of needing to know.